# 2 Samba Configs: "config file" Parameter Fails

Tags: configuration, samba, samba4

I am attempting to create 2 separate shares using 2 very different configs.  I can get both going individually from the same system, but not together.  Regretfully, I still have some legacy systems that require NT1.  I am attempting to build this out as a proxy for SMBv3.

**The ask**: What parameter/setting am I missing in order to create shares using *2 separate authentication levels*?

Primary **smb.conf**

```
[global]

config file = /etc/samba/mfg/smb.conf.%m

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server min protocol = NT1
```

Referencing the proper **machine** file **smb.conf.server**

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
   workgroup = NETBIOSDOMAIN
   dns proxy = no
   realm = mydomain.local
   security = ads
   password server = MYMASKEDDC01.mydomain.local
#   client signing = if_required
#   kerberos method = secrets and keytab

#### Debugging/Accounting ####


# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   log level = 5
   map to guest = bad user
   max log size = 1000
```

The error logs actually refer to the IP of the server, not the actual hostname.  (suspect?: This may be my smoking gun as its not pulling NETBIOS info ?)

```
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.513607,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3861(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_sesssetup.c:146
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.513904,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.513918,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.513925,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.513931,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.513939,  4] ../../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:319(set_sec_ctx_internal)
  setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2023/01/17 12:55:56.514512,  3] ../../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:220(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

Reiterating: *If I use the smbv3 config as a stand alone **smb.conf** file, everything resolves properly & permissions map as expected.*